# How to get properties from a Polygon object?

Tags: geometry, polygons, properties

We can get polygons by this code:

```
polys = (SeedRandom[#]; Polygon[RandomInteger[20, {4, 2}]]) & /@ Range[6]
```

[image]

How to get those properties? When I dig `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Polygon] ``, I know

- **"Number of points"**

`` Region`PolygonDump`polygonCoordinateCount[#] &[polys[[1]]] ``

> 4

- **Embedding dimension**

`` Region`PolygonDump`polygonEmbeddingDimension[#] &[polys[[1]]] ``

> 2

- **"Type"**

`` Region`PolygonDump`polygonType@@Region`PolygonDump`computeType[polys[[1]]] ``

> "degenerated polygon"

- **Bounds**

`` Region`PolygonDump`iRegionBounds[polys[[1]]] ``

> {{0, 7}, {0, 3}}

- **Area**

`` Region`PolygonDump`iArea[polys[[1]]] ``

> undefined

But it seem too dirty. Is there any *mma-style* method to make this?

Comment: `p=((SeedRandom[#]; Polygon[RandomInteger[20, {4, 2}]]) & /@ Range[1])[[1]]; FullForm[p]` shows me that `Length[p[[1]]]` tells me the number of points.

Comment: @Bill, this will work correctly only for non-disconnected polygons. It will not work for something like `pDis = Polygon[{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]`. The simple way is to just use the internal function: ```With[{coords = pDis[[1]]}, Region`PolygonDump`coordinateCount[coords]]```.

Comment: A look at the output of `MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@Polygon[RandomInteger[20, {4, 2}]]` shows many of them are computed on the fly by internal functions, such as the one pointed out by @Domen. The code for these function, at least the couple I checked, can be inspected.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

poly = RandomPolygon[4]
```

[image]

For a given polygon:

```
coords = PolygonCoordinates[poly]

(* {{0.0116446, 0.927266}, {0.0862234, 0.377913}, {0.543757, 
  0.479332}, {0.876608, 0.521964}} *)

nbrPts = Length[coords]

(* 4 *)

SimplePolygonQ[poly]

(* True *)

bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose[coords]

(* {{0.0116446, 0.876608}, {0.377913, 0.927266}} *)

area = Area[poly]

(* 0.0930163 *)

Perimeter[poly]

(* 2.92281 *)
```

Comment: `PolygonCoordinates[polys[[3]]]` will get 5 points. Also `polys[[1]]`

Comment: Also: `RegionEmbeddingDimension@poly` gives `2` and `bounds = Transpose@(List @@ BoundingRegion@poly)`

Comment: @yode - If the polygons are to be "well-behaved" they must be simple polygons. To get simple polygons, use `RandomPolygon`. Compare `Length[Select[SeedRandom[1234]; Polygon /@ RandomInteger[20, {100, 4, 2}], SimplePolygonQ]]` (53) with `Length[Select[SeedRandom[1234]; RandomPolygon[20, 100], SimplePolygonQ]]` (100)